# Default several values of Parameter, SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, dax

I am trying to predefine some report parameter properties in SSRS, where the dataset is retrieved using DAX. I want one parameter, that selects an area code, to be default set as "(SELECT ALL)". How can I do this? If I try to just select it from the default value list the best I get is:

```
=First(Fields!City_Areacode_.Value, "AreaDetails")
```

I don't want the First value, however, but all values. Is my best option to "hard code" all the values in there as a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way is to select "Get values from a query" and then select the correct dataset and column instead of "Specify values".